# Capitalize in python

Tags: python, list, capitalize

I want to write a program that first ask the user how many lines then program should capitalize the input here is the code:

```
n=int(input(''))
1<=n<=10
name3 = []
counter = 0

while counter < n:
    if  n > 10:
        print('!')
        n=int(input(''))
    else:
        name=input('')
        sp = name.split(' ')
        for i in sp:
            name2=i.capitalize()
            name3.append(name2)
        counter +=1
    
for i in name3:
     print(i, end = ' ')
```

input should be like this:

```
2
hello world
this is me
```

result should be like this:

```
Hello World
This Is Me
```

but in my code result is:

```
Hello World This Is Me
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You should not store the tokens independently on the list:

```py
n=int(input(''))
1<=n<=10
name3 = []
counter = 0

while counter < n:
    if  n > 10:
        print('!')
        n=int(input(''))
    else:
        name=input('')
        sp = name.split(' ')
        name2 = []
        # store capitalized tokens on a new list
        for i in sp:
            name2.append(i.capitalize())
        # join the tokens back together and append
        name3.append(' '.join(name2))
        counter +=1

# use '\n' as suggested by others
for i in name3:
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your print statement specifies the "end" to be a space. The default is a newline character, which will give you what you want.

**Edit:** you also need to recombine the words before appending the string to your list. This preserves the grouping by sentence.

```
while counter < n:
    if  n > 10:
        print('!')
        n=int(input(''))
    else:
        name=input('')
        sp = name.split(' ')
        name3.append(" ".join([i.capitalize() for i in sp]))
        counter +=1
    
for i in name3:
     print(i)
```

Comment: when I remove end= ' ' then each word is printing in new line, I want to print each line in input in a separate line

Comment: This doesn't work. Capitalize only acts on the first character of the string, so the result would be `Hello world` and not `Hello World` as requested

Comment: I realised I misunderstood what you wanted. I've edited the answer -  hopefully this does what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this in the else block.

```py
name=input('')
sp = name.split(' ')
name2 = []
for i in sp:
    name2.append(i.capitalize())
name3.append(' '.join(name2))
counter +=1
```